Apply cacheDynamicVersionsFor/cacheChangingModulesFor on a specific dependency configuration?
just want to refresh specific dependency only.
here's my try, but not working, seeking for some suggestions for modification
configurations {
    snapShotUpdateEveryTime.extendsFrom implementation
}

dependencies {
    snapShotUpdateEveryTime 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
}

configurations.snapShotUpdateEveryTime {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 0, 'seconds'
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think you want:
configurations {
   snapShotUpdateEveryTime
   implementation.extendsFrom snapShotUpdateEveryTime
}

so that dependencies added to snapShotUpdateEveryTime are picked up in implementation.
You can also put all the configuration code for snapShotUpdateEveryTime in the configurations block, which would further change it to:
configurations {
   snapShotUpdateEveryTime {
      resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
      resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 0, 'seconds'
   }
   implementation.extendsFrom snapShotUpdateEveryTime
}

Also, it looks like you are only concerned with dependencies declared with dynamic version numbers, or those explicitly declared as snapshots in their version number (the latter of which are marked as changing automatically (docs)). If you want to mark all dependencies as changing in the configuration, you can add to the snapShotUpdateEveryTime block:
withDependencies { configureEach { if (it instanceof ExternalModuleDependency) it.changing = true } }

